# Does Hogwarts Legacy have multiple endings?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I've been playing Hogwarts Legacy for a month and haven't completed the game. There are so many path-specific conversation options, I can choose not to learn unforgivable curses. Given the fact that Sebastian Sallow's uncle

> does not want you and Sebastian to use unforgivable curses after Sebastian used Imperio on the goblin to protect his younger sister,

Will learning unforgivable curses (and using them) lead you to become a dark wizard or something along the same lines?

So, if there is more than one ending, it would be helpful if anyone could tell me what I need to do to cause the branching, other than learning unforgivable curses (such as picking a good-ish option in conversation?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to keep the amount of spoilers to the minimum.

Yes, the game has multiple ending.
You have two "basic" endings - a good ending and an evil ending, but what ending you get is decided with just one single question at the end of the game. Anything you do before has no significance at all in that regard. Even learning the curses or using them has little effect.

Ironically, there is an actual bigger choice that happens during the game:

> you will be able to get Sebastian expelled... but don't expect any big change to come from that other than the game actually trying to make you feel bad for it and losing the ability to learn the curses forever afterward (since he won't be present)

There is also one more ending - the True ending - that is available after you complete the game. It is not really tied to the plot and ignores completely what base ending you got ("evil" ending? yup, no one cares). I will leave you the surprise to see what this is about, but you should probably already guess it. Hint: what do you expect to happen at the end of the courses?

Comment: Thanks! Assuming you've completed the game at least once, is there any system like NG+? Or just plain new game only?

Comment: @Skye-AT nope. It is a good enough game, but it lacks some highly demanded features like this one. Quidditch and an actual companion/follower system are some other features that apparently many players want

Comment: Oh, that's sad to hear. I don't know if I can have fun at Quidditch (judging by Quidditch World Cup), but having follower/companion sounds fun. Anyway, thanks for the info!